# Applying a function to an aliased field

Tags: mysql

I have a query that creates two aliased files like this:

```
 (CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLongitude` ELSE `specialLongitude` END) AS `longitude`
 (CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLatitude` ELSE `specialLatitude` END) AS `latitude`
```

which determine which longitude and latitude to use in a certain query (there are numerous JOIN's in the table, but for the sake of this example, the only JOIN is from the `Gigs` table performing a `NATURAL LEFT JOIN` to a table called `Venues`.

That bit works fine and returns the venue co-ordinates I am interested in doing a distance calculation that I can then order by.

The distance field looks like this:

```
((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(`latitude` * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(`latitude` * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon - `longitude`) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)
```

But when I run the query, I get the error `Unknown column 'latitude' in 'field list'`. Does anyone know how I can perform such a lookup.

p.s.

Although I know I can use geospatial queries, I would like to know the answer in a way that could later be used for further queries, i.e.

```
SELECT *,(CASE WHEN `a` > 0 THEN `a` ELSE `b` END) AS `x`,(`x` MOD 3) AS `y` FROM `Foo`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways :

a) replace the aliases with SQL

b) Encapsulate your first query by another one like this :

```
     SELECT 
          t.latitude,
          t.longitude, 
          ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(t.latitude * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon - t.longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) as distance

     FROM ( 
       SELECT ((CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLongitude` ELSE `specialLongitude` END) AS `longitude`, (CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLatitude` ELSE `specialLatitude` END) AS `latitude` FROM Gigs left join Venues on ....
     ) as t
```

Comment: Damn, was hoping for a simpler answer, but alas, I did think it was something of a pipe dream. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `SELECT` the distance, then I believe you need to re-declare the case for the value. AKA: Rather than using `SELECT col alias1, alias1 + 1 alias2` you have to do `SELECT col alias1, col + 1 alias2`. Take a look at this MySQL documentation on [Where you can use column aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html).

If you just want to `GROUP BY` the distance, then you can use your aliases in your distance function. However, if you want to `SELECT` the distance, you need to replace the alias usage in your distance function with the evaluated `CASE` code.

`ORDER BY` using aliases:

```
SELECT
  (CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLongitude` ELSE `specialLongitude` END) longitude,
  (CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLatitude` ELSE `specialLatitude` END) latitude
FROM table_name
ORDER BY ((ACOS(SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(longitude * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)
```

`SELECT` cannot use the aliases (it gets messy!):

```
SELECT
  (CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLongitude` ELSE `specialLongitude` END) longitude,
  (CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLatitude` ELSE `specialLatitude` END) latitude,
  (
    ((ACOS(SIN((CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLatitude` ELSE `specialLatitude` END) * PI() / 180) * SIN((CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLatitude` ELSE `specialLatitude` END) * PI() / 180) + COS((CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLatitude` ELSE `specialLatitude` END) * PI() / 180) * COS((CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLatitude` ELSE `specialLatitude` END) * PI() / 180) * COS((CASE WHEN `venueID` > 0 THEN `venueLongitude` ELSE `specialLongitude` END) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)
  ) distance
FROM table_name
ORDER BY distance
```